# how to map API list data to single checkbox? in flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox

Hi i am new to flutter i need help in getting API data and display with a checkbox to select and deselect.
i have used sample API database which contains the information of 10 users. I want to display Users Id, name, Username, company name and  phone number as a card or list tile per user. I also want to assign single checkbox per card/list tile with check / uncheck functionality.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_http_get/example.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_http_get/screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_http_get/sunday_state.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Sunday(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's My ApI Get method

```
class Sunday extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sunday({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SundayState createState() => _SundayState();
}

class _SundayState extends State<Sunday> {
  var users = [];
  Future getUserData() async {
    var res =
        await http.get(Uri.https("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", "users"));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(res.body) as List;

    setState(() {
      users = jsonData;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserData();
  }
```

here's my build method

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("User Data"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: users.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                final post = users[i];

                return Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
                          // singlecheckbox(notification),
                          ...notification.map(singlecheckbox).toList(),
                          Text("${post['id']}"),
                          Text("${post['name']}"),
                          
                        ])
```

here's my widget to toggle check box

```
final notification = [SundayCheckBoxState()];
void togglegroupcheckbox(bool? value) {
    if (value == null) return;
    setState(() {
      // notification.value = value;
      notification.forEach((element) => element.value = value);
    });
  }

  Widget singlecheckbox(SundayCheckBoxState checkbox) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      activeColor: Colors.green,
      value: checkbox.value,
      // title: Text('${users.last['name']}'),
      onChanged: togglegroupcheckbox,

      
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options, one of them is using a `ListTile` and add a `CheckBox` to the beginning (or end) of each row. You have too keep track the state of each checkbox, for example in your `users` list.

Try to define your `ListView.builder` like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: users.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    final post = users[i];

    return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
              // singlecheckbox(notification),
              //...notification.map(singlecheckbox).toList(),
              ListTile(
                  isThreeLine: true,
                  leading: Checkbox(
                    value: post["checked"] ?? false,
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        post["checked"] = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                      "${post['name']}\n${post['company']['name']}"),
                  subtitle: Text("${post['email']}"),
                  trailing: Text("${post['username']}"))
            ])));
  })
```

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome. You might want to consider marking my answer as accepted and / or upvote, if you found it helpful.